# Disable slickgrid horizontal scrollbar

Tags: slickgrid

I need to disable slickgrid horizontal scrollbar. I have only one column and  have forceFitColumns : true.

Is possible?

Thanks

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You can do this with a little css. Try adding this to your page.

```
   .slick-viewport {
    overflow-x: hidden !important;
}
```

Note that the !important is important because the style gets inlined by the grid code so this overrides it...

HTH